# Symfony - Throw an exception returning 403 from a Listener

Tags: symfony, authorization, listener, api-platform.com, access-denied

I'm using `Symfony5` with `ApiPlatform`

I'm using a `Listener` for multiple tasks including to do some `authorization` that I can't do in my voters.

So through a simple condition I verify what field of my entity is being modified.

I go through the modified fields, and check if they're different from the only field that can be modified.

here's how :

```
$modifiedValues = $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($eventArgs->getObject());

foreach ($modifiedValues as $key => $value) {
    if ("statut" != $key) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('Vous ne pouvez pas modifier ce champ.');
    }    
}
```

Now I'm throwing an `AccessDeniedException` which I thought would return a `403` but actually return a `500`.

The `authorization` part is actually working but I'm a bit bothered by this "exception" in my logic, cause other authorization rules will return either `200` or `403`.

So my questions would be:

- Does anyone know why this exception behave this way ? If it's normal behavior or something's off
- Is there another way to return a `403` from this `Listener` ?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: "statut" do you mean "status"

Comment: french habits, thanks for the input. If you got smthg on the listener thing though I'd be gratefull

Comment: I think I can help you provide some more information. So in your case, it returned a 500 error code, so please check on the var/dev.log, maybe you can find the reason. Else can you put a line which contains "CRITICAL" so I can help you debug

Comment: look at the document , you can create a class and use it , or customizing all access denied responses  https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_denied_handler.html#customize-the-forbidden-response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/errors/) you can configure the framework to catch your exception.

#### config/packages/api_platform.yaml

```yaml
api_platform:
    exception_to_status:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException: 403
```

But you should probably create your own Exception class, extend it from AcessDeniedException and configure it.

#### src/Exception/AccessDeniedException.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Exception;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;

class MyAccessDeniedException extends AccessDeniedException
{
}
```

#### config/packages/api_platform.yaml

```yaml
api_platform:
    exception_to_status:
        App\Exception\MyAccessDeniedException: 403
```

#### Listener.php

```php
$modifiedValues = $eventArgs->getEntityManager()->getUnitOfWork()->getEntityChangeSet($eventArgs->getObject());

foreach ($modifiedValues as $key => $value) {
    if ("statut" != $key) {
        throw new MyAccessDeniedException('Vous ne pouvez pas modifier ce champ.');
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm on another task as of now but will come back on this issue once I've tested that (which I think is exactly what I needed) and will let you know.

Comment: Your answer did solve my issue, thanks a lot !